# What software is available for managing sites in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, open-source

We are looking for a simple tool that allows us to quickly add and remove sites in Apache. Currently we are editing the httpd.conf file, but we want to make it easier for less technical people to add new sites.

I know we could code a simple script to do this, but it would be better if we could find an existing open source tool/script.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used either of them, but a couple of well-respected options seem to be:

Apache Admin - http://www.fileguru.com/Apache-Admin/info (if you don't mind paying)

Comanche - http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/comanche.html